# difference between SDL and GLUT

Tags: c, eclipse, graphics, sdl, glut

I am learning the Opengl graphic programming at Eclipse. Can someone tell me the difference between GLUT application and SDL application, so that I can dig into either one of them? Tks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SDL is a larger library for larger needs.

If you're building a simple demo of a rendering mechanism, GLUT is way better than SDL, it takes care of a lot of the details that SDL would otherwise require.

However, if you're developing a serious application, SDL is more likely to be the tool you need to use, as GLUT abstracts more than a real application would normally want to. SDL gives you much more control over everything.

Answer (score 1):

SDL is a full multimedia library, which supports graphics, sound, input, networking plus there are a lot third-party add-ons. GLUT is a simple GUI library.